# Sobrecarga de constructores c++

Tags: c++, constructor, operador, sobrecarga

Se me asignó el siguiente problema:

> Se requiere un programa que permita realizar diferentes tipos de operaciones matemáticas con diferentes tipos de datos.
>   Las operaciones matemáticas que deberá realizar son las siguientes:
>
> 1. Suma
> 2. Resta
> 3. Multiplicación
> 4. División
>
> Adicional cada operación realizara deberá poderse hacer para los siguientes tipos de datos:
>
> 1. Int
> 2. Doble
> 3. Char (se debe convertir las cadenas de texto a número para realizar las operaciones).
>
> Implemente la clase de tal forma que al usar el objeto se puedan proveer dos y tres parámetros de los tipos de datos.
>   También, la clase debe tener al menos dos constructores uno por defecto y al menos uno con parámetros iniciales es decir los números con los que se desea realizar operaciones.

Y para dar solución estoy intentando hacer una sobrecarga de constructores y que en ellos haga una operación aritmética según sus parámetros adjunto clase **Operaciones.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Operaciones{
private:
    int n1,n2;
    double dn1,dn2;
    char cn1,cn2;
    string resultado;

public:
    Operaciones();

    Operaciones(int n1,char op,int n2){
        this->n1=n1;
        this->n2=n2;
        switch(op){
            case '+':
                resultado= to_string(this->n1+this->n2);
            break;
            case '-':
                resultado= to_string(this->n1-this->n2);
            break;
            case '*':
                resultado= to_string(this->n1*this->n2);
            break;
            case '/':
                resultado= to_string(this->n1/this->n2);
            break;
        }
    }

    Operaciones(double dn1,char op,double dn2){
        this->n1=dn1;
        this->n2=dn2;
        switch(op){
            case '+':
                resultado= to_string(this->n1+this->n2);
            break;
            case '-':
                resultado= to_string(this->n1-this->n2);
            break;
            case '*':
                resultado= to_string(this->n1*this->n2);
            break;
            case '/':
                resultado= to_string(this->n1/this->n2);
            break;
        }
    }

    Operaciones(char *cn1,char op,char *cn2){
        this->n1=atoi(cn1);
        this->n2=atoi(cn2);
        switch(op){
            case '+':
                resultado= to_string(this->n1+n2);
            break;
            case '-':
                resultado= to_string(this->n1-n2);
            break;
            case '*':
                resultado= to_string(this->n1*n2);
            break;
            case '/':
                resultado= to_string(this->n1/n2);
            break;
        }
    }

    void mostrarResultado(){
        cout<<resultado;
    }

    ~Operaciones(){
        cout<<"Objeto destruido"<<endl;
    }


};
```

pero a la hora de llamarlo en el main me da error y no dice nada en especifico, adjunto **main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Operaciones.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Operaciones sumaEnteros(5,'+',4);
    sumaEnteros.mostrarResultado;

    return 0;
}
```

El error es  este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y ya no sé que hacer :( **¿alguien sabe que podría ser?**

Comment: agrega parentesis en la llamada de tu funcion: `sumaEnteros.mostrarResultado()`, adems creo que esta mal instanciad tu objeto `sumaEnteros`. creo que deberia de ser asi: `Operaciones sumaEnteros= new Operaciones(5,'+',4);`

Comment: @Shassain ¿y por qué debería usar `new`? Que yo sepa en C++ se pueden crear objetos sin acudir a la memoria dinámica. Además, si usas `new`, entonces `sumaEnteros` debería ser un puntero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos errores de bulto en tu código:

**Función sin paréntesis**

```
sumaEnteros.mostrarResultado;
```

`mostrarResultado` es una función y, por tanto, necesita paréntesis:

```
sumaEnteros.mostrarResultado();
```

**Include incorrecto**

Fíjate que en el main estás incluyendo el cpp en vez de la cabecera:

```
#include "Operaciones.cpp"
```

El include esperado es este:

```
#include "Operaciones.h"
```

Ya que la cabecera es lo que necesita el compilador para concocer el tamaño que ocupa el objeto y ćomo se han de invocar a las funciones miembro (si son estáticas, virtuales, ...)